# Pandas time series index from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to use the pandas library for time series analysis in python.
My data is now stored as a list of dictionaries:

```
mydata = [
{
    'date': datetime.date(2013, 1, 1),
    'snow_depth': 1.0,
}, {
    'date': datetime.date(2013, 1, 2),
    'snow_depth': 2.5,
}, {
    'date': datetime.date(2013, 1, 3),
    'snow_depth': 8.0,
},
]
```

I use the following command to get a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(mydata).set_index('date')
```

But the index is not recognized as a DateTimeIndex, but only as an object:

```
df.index
```

returns: `Index([2013-01-01, 2013-01-02, 2013-01-03], dtype='object')`

So, I can't do some of the time series operations in Pandas, like aggregate by month and so on. When I run `df.index` I'm expecting to get something like:

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-01, ..., 2013-01-03]
Length: 3, Freq: D, Timezone: None
```

How do I create the DataFrame from the list when I require the index to be a `DateTimeIndex`?

Comment: try, df.index = pd.to_datetime( df.index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also convert the index to a `DatetimeIndex` directly:

```
In [159]: df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)

In [160]: df.index
Out[160]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-01, ..., 2013-01-03]
Length: 3, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Answer (score 4):

Pandas `DateTimeIndex` can be a bit particular. For example, it doesn't like `datetime.date` values. But if you change them to `datetime.datetime` values, it works as expected. Same call signature, even.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
mydata = [
{
    'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1),
    'snow_depth': 1.0,
}, {
    'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 2),
    'snow_depth': 2.5,
}, {
    'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 3),
    'snow_depth': 8.0,
},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(mydata).set_index('date')
```

Make sure you're running a recent version, though. 0.11 and below were even more particular (and less helpful) about throwing `DateTimeIndex` related errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas.to_datetime() function to convert the type automatically to datetime. check out this tutorial: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html
it has many basic usages for time series analysis.